# SwiftUI go back to RootView in sceneWillEnterForeground SceneDelegate.swift

Tags: swiftui

we try to reset the current View to Root if App will enter Foreground.

How can we do that in SwiftUI?

```
func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
      let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let contentView = RootView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let singleOrder = SingleOrder()
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(singleOrder))
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "go back" but the possible approach is to recreate root view controller, by moving "by default" generated content creation into other delegate method as below...

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        self.window = window
    }
}


func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let contentView = RootView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    let singleOrder = SingleOrder()
    window?.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(singleOrder))
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: but if we recreate the view. what's happened with the other view ? load two times?

Comment: which other view? the code should be "moved", not "copied".

Comment: i moved the code to this part but it duplicates the view every time the app come foreground.

Comment: i think we need to delete the old scene or view.

Comment: moment... it recreates the window... I'll update in a moment

Comment: updated, the creation of window and content view separated, so window remains the same, but root controller is recreated on entering foreground.

Comment: ok nice idea but can you help to implement my updated code into your idea ??

Comment: okay thanks but. if you run a timer in RootView() you get a duplicate running everytime !!! that's bad

Comment: Resetting internal content is out of topic... it's on you.